# Iterate DataTable() to get td value of every row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have created a table with DataTable() plugin: [DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/)

Every row has a td with "amount" class.
I want to iterate all rows to get all td values and save the sum into a variable.

I found this: [each()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/each()), but I don't know how to integrate it.

**UPDATE**: code generated by DataTable()

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>World</td>                              
            <td class="amount">346.387,81</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>World</td>                              
            <td class="amount">444.392,35</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: share the html of datatable generated

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, done.

Comment: your table will use pages??

Comment: @Vanojx1, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Datables will create pages of data when needed... for ex with 1000 rows datables will create something like 100 pages with 10 rows. In this case an each function using td selector wont work.

Comment: @Vanojx1, exactly! It is the same thing that I said in a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var totalamount = 0;
$('#table td.amount').each(function(){
   totalamount += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",",""),10)
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1c1fbaty/)**

Comment: I already tried so. The problem is that the table content appears in different "views" in the same page that I can slide. But, using your code, there will be iterate only the rows shown in the view selected in that moment. 
I must use dataTable plugin to iterate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In [their documentation](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html), there is an example that does exactly what you want to achive.

Take a look at the snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    footerCallback: function(row, data, start, end, display) {
      var api = this.api();

      function intVal(i) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
          typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
      };

      // Total over this page
      var total = api
        .column(1, {
          page: 'current'
        })
        .data()
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        });

      // Update footer
      $(api.column(1).footer()).html(
        total
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will parse the entire dataset and return the total:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.clear();
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
  var rows = oTable.fnSettings().aoData;
  var columnIndex = 1;
  var total = 0;

  $.each(rows, function(i, val) {
    total += parseFloat(val._aData[columnIndex].replace(/,/g, ""));
  });

  alert(total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```